# Rails set layout from within a before_filter method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, before-filter

Is it possible to reset a default layout from within a before_filter method in Rails 3?

I have the following as my **contacts_controller.rb**:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :admin_required, :only => [:index, :show]
  def show
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @contact }
    end
  end
  [...]
end
```

And the following in my **application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout 'usual_layout'
  private
  def admin_required
    if !authorized?          # please, ignore it. this is not important
      redirect_to[...]
      return false
    else
      layout 'admin'  [???]  # this is where I would like to define a new layout
      return true
    end
  end
end
```

I know I could just put...

```
layout 'admin', :only => [:index, :show]
```

... right after "before_filter" in "ContactsController", but, as I already have a bunch of other controllers with many actions properly being filtered as admin-required ones, it would be much easer if I could just reset the layout from "usual_layout" to "admin" inside the "admin_required" method.

BTW, by putting...

```
layout 'admin'
```

...inside "admin_required" (as I tried in the code above), I get an undefined method error message. It seems to work only outside of defs, just like I did for "usual_layout".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

From [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html), `2.2.13.2 Choosing Layouts at Runtime`:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  layout :products_layout

  private

  def products_layout
    @current_user.special? ? "special" : "products"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks apneadiving, but this is not exactly what I meant. I already have a method being pre-executed properly on a bunch of controllers, filtering the very same actions that should be rendered with this special layout. But this method is triggered by a before_filter command. I don't want to replace each before_filter on every controller by a layout command now pointing to a method from within I would get the proper layout name - or add it anyway. I need to define the special layout from within the very same method already triggered by the before_filter command.

Comment: Well, I decided to follow apneadiving's suggestion. It took me a while but I replaced every 'before_filter :admin_required, :only => [...]' by 'layout :admin_required, :only => [...]'. It worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: could anyone explain what this line means? `@current_user.special? ? "special" : "products"` thanks!!

Comment: @Lucas its a ternary operator

Answer (score 18):

If for some reason you cannot modify the existing controller and/or just want to do this in a before filter you can  use `self.class.layout :special` here is an example:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  layout :products
  before_filter :set_special_layout

  private

  def set_special_layout
    self.class.layout :special if @current_user.special?
  end
end
```

It's just another way to do essential the same thing. More options make for happier programmers!!

Comment: The huge problem I ran into with this method though is that the layout gets cached by Rails, and therefore can apply even when it's not supposed to. Thread safety or some such. Use the `layout :set_layout` and `def set_layout` way, much safer :)

Answer (score 2):

The modern way of doing this is to use a proc,

```
layout proc { |controller| user.logged_in? "layout1" : "layout2" }
```