# Rails Set Layout Based on URL Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, render, url-parameters

So I am trying to change the layout of a view based on url params.

So far, I figured out I have to set the layout in the controller. In my controller under the show action I have:

```
if params['iframe'] == 'true'
  render :layout => 'vendored'
end
```

The layout 'vendored' exists in views/layouts. I am getting the dreaded rendering multiple times. Here is the rest of the show action in my controller:

```
 def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @user = current_user
    @approved_employers = current_user.get_employers_approving_event(@event) if user_signed_in?
    respond_with(@event)
```

The problem is that I don't see another render. I don't see another one in the entire controller. Of course, there is a render somewhere because it is rendering my default application layout, is that causing the problem? I read in the rails docs that I can add

```
and return
```

to the end and that should fix the problem, but not sure where to put that since the two renders are not next to each other. I also don't see any other redirect_to's either. Where should I be looking for this other render? Is that the problem?

Comment: FWIW, respond_with eventually calls render...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672385/rails-set-layout-from-within-a-before-filter-method). For your case:

```
  before_filter :set_layout, :only => [:show]

  private

  def set_layout
   self.class.layout ( params['iframe'] == 'true' ? 'vendored' :  'application')
  end
```

Comment: Seems like should work. Though now I am getting:

    Could not render layout: undefined local variable or method `vendored' for #<EventsController:0x007ff937c8bd50>

Tried it with application too, but got the same error. Do I need to tell it where the layout is or something?

Comment: @KevinZ try using `'vendored'` instead of the symbol also need to set the default layout if not true

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, I think this is easier to understand:

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  layout :iframe_layout

  private

  def iframe_layout
    params['iframe'] ? "vendored" : "application"
  end
end
```