# Rails 4: Layout file outside 'views/layouts' folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, path

By default, rails look for layout view files in `views/layouts` path. However, I want to change it to `app/themes/theme-name/layout.html.erb` for a specific controller. For this I'm using following code:

```
class ContentController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_theme

  def set_theme
    theme = "default"
    prepend_view_path "app/themes/#{theme}" # change default view path
    self.class.layout "../../themes/#{theme}/layout" # change default layout path
  end
end
```

But this code is throwing following error:

```
Missing template layouts/../../themes/default/layout with {:locale=>[:en], :format .....
```

It is still looking in the layouts folder. How can I resolve the issue.

Answer (score 5):

<strike>Replace this line:</strike>

```
self.class.layout "../../themes/#{theme}/layout"
```

with this:

```
self.class.layout Rails.root+"/themes/#{theme}/layout"
```

### Update:

By default Rails looks for layouts in the `app/view/layouts` folder. This is the path that is configured for use. To add another path like `app/themes/theme-name/layouts` to the list of view paths, you need to add it to the `config/application.rb` like this:

```
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    config.paths["app/views"] << "app/themes/theme-name/"
    ...
  end
```

Restart the server. Now, if you have a layout file "alpha.html.erb" inside `app/themes/theme-name/layouts` folder, you can use it in your controller like this:

```
layout "alpha"
```

Rails will look for `layouts/alpha.html.erb` in the configured paths.

You can always improvise on this to suit your needs. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, using this code, the controller view file loads but the layout for this file is still not loading. I've confirmed it using the webpage source code. And in the tab instead of actual title it is stating "Action Controller: Exception Caught"

Comment: That's because you're missing the layout option in the controller. Either replace before_filter with layout or look at this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672385/rails-set-layout-from-within-a-before-filter-method  for more options. There are multiple ways of doing this.

Comment: I've tried replacing before_filter with layout it is not working either. I've updated the code above to introduce some additional code in `set_theme` method which might also needs to be considered.